# How to avoid slider image what covers whole width of screen and certain height to stretch or crop?

Tags: html, css, image, slider

I'm working on a website. There's one problem. The slider won't fit in the frame without stretching.

Slider Image is full width of screen and i have defined height for it.

In CSS part i have applied `object-fit: cover` but this crop my image

I hope you guys can help me out on this. I'd tried alot and also asked some other people but they can't help me with this.

Or Should i restrict my client to use image of that resolution only?

Comment: Could you please provide some code ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Mostly you should restrict the client from using different ratios, or resolutions, because you are using the full width aaaaand defined height, defined height is very limiting in your case, what you can do is use

```
 object-fit:cover;
 object-fit:center;
```

but that doesn't stop the cropping it will just focus on the center of the image when cropping.